# I cannot insert these ^ character within \textcolor in lstlisting

Tags: listings

I want to highlight some parts of my Turtle document (with a specific color) in the lstlisting element as you can see in my MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor} %with special prdefined colors 

\lstset{ basicstyle=\ttfamily,breaklines=true}
\lstset{escapeinside={<@}{@>}}


\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}[language=SPARQL,keywordstyle=\color{blue},basicstyle=\normalsize\ttfamily]
b:Shakespeare foaf:givenName <@\textcolor{NavyBlue}{"William"^^xsd:string}@>.
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

However, as the result instead of "Shakespeare"^^xsd:string, I have  "William"8sd:string. The coloring is actually all right, but I couldn't prevent showing 8 instead of ^^.

Answer (score 3):

Between `<@` and `@>`, TeX uses its standard rules and these rules say that a combination like `^^x` refers to the character whose ASCII code differs from the ASCII code of `x` by 64 (plus or minus, depending on which operation gives a value in the interval 0–127). Thus `^^x` gives `8`.

Actually the rule is a bit more complicated: if the two characters following `^^` are among `0123456789abcdef`, they are interpreted as a hexadecimal 16 bit number. However, `x` doesn't make this particular rule to apply.

Solution: use `\string`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor} %with special prdefined colors 

\lstset{
  basicstyle=\ttfamily,
  breaklines=true,
  escapeinside={<@}{@>},
  columns=fullflexible,
}


\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}[language=SPARQL,keywordstyle=\color{blue},basicstyle=\normalsize\ttfamily]
b:Shakespeare foaf:givenName <@\textcolor{NavyBlue}{"William"\string^\string^xsd:string}@>.
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

I believe it's better to use `columns=fullflexible` to get uniform spacing.

[image]

Comment: Thank you egreg for your detailed answer. This solved my problem.